# Can a game with a pure strategy Nash equilibrium also have mixed strategy equilibria?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have questions:

1. If zero-sum game has pure strategy Nash equilibrium (saddle point), can it have also mixed strategy equilibria?
2. What if game is not zero-sum?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the first question, but for the second question it definitely exists: consider a game with two players who can both choose left $(L,l)$ and right $(R,r)$ and the following payoff matrix:

[image: Payoff matrix]

Clearly, there are two pure strategy Nash equilibria: $(L,l)$ and $(R,r)$. However, there is also a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium where Player 1 chooses $L$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and Player 2 chooses $l$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: You can actually technically satisfy the first question also by just giving a game with all zeros. That is, take your game and replace the 2's and 1's with zeros, and _any_ profile (mixed or pure) is a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: While that's true, it's a bit of a trivial result. What if we restrict the question to games where at least one payoff is nonzero?

Comment: Sure, make the payoffs in each cell (1,-1) and the same argument holds! I think maybe the existence of a _unique_ pure NE in a zero sum game might preclude the existence of a mixed NE.

Comment: There's a mainstream game-theoretic example that has almost this exact payoff matrix, and indeed, it has two pure and one mixed equilibria:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_sexes_(game_theory)